# Stackoverflow - statistics update

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

Two days ago I got some upvotes on stackoverflow but my Tags report doesn't show it:

[image]

Is there a way to manually update it or should I wait for the site to update it automatically - btw how often are tags for answers calculated for each user?

Comment: They are normally updated daily at 03:00 UTC, but they've been having problems with database timeouts lately.